# How do I find the absolute path to a Play Framework app?

Tags: java, scala, playframework

At the moment I'm working with a team on a Play! Framework app. With the next user story, I have to implement some different file modifications, such as moving a file to a defined directory.

Because we are working on different platforms, I'm not always really sure if the app has the right path. So I want to work with a absolute path of the app directory.

How do I get the absolute path of a Play! app? Is there a method for this?

Comment: "At the moment I'm working in a team on a play! framework app." 
Cool!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**This answer applies only to older versions of the Play Framework, before v2.**

Play has an application path property:

```
String projectRoot = Play.applicationPath;
```

This will give you the directory that Play is running from.

I think a better practice is moving the directory outside of your project install directory and placing the path to it in your `application.conf` as a property. You then retrieve it when needed. For example:

*Application.conf:*

```
my.file.path=/tmp/whatever
```

*Code:*

```
String projectRoot = Play.configuration.getProperty("my.file.path");
```

Comment: This doesn't work on the version of Play I'm using (2.1.1). Looks like the correct way to get the application path is:  String path = Play.application().path().getPath();

Answer (score 12):

Since version **2.5.0**, `play.Play` class is deprecated. It is recommended to inject `play.Environment` and use the method as follows:

```
public File rootPath();
```

The `play.Environment` singleton also contains some very handy method, which provide files by relative path e.g.

```
public File getFile(String relativePath);
public URL resource(String relativePath);
public InputStream resourceAsStream(String relativePath);
```

Comment: Could you please show where and how to inject this Environment ?

Comment: @JulienD, the best way (that may depend on your application requirements and design though) would be to use `play.Environment` in your module. Please look at this example: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Configurable-bindings - you can use environment instace while creating your beans / services etc.

Answer (score 10):

As of play 2.0: play.Play.application().path().getAbsolutePath()

Answer (score 3):

Neither of those worked on my version of play, so I used this instead:
Play.current().path().getAbsolutePath()